# Simultanous press and pinch

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

How can I implement simultaneous press and pinch with `hammer js` or other libraries?

The main idea is to press with the right finger and pinch with the left hand (two fingers), the only issue in here is that I don't know how this could be obtained since after pressing with the right hand a further pinch won't be recognized. Is there a way to actually ignore the first press so that the upcoming two fingers can be recognized as a pinch?